# Pass variables with PresentViewController in Swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm working on a swift application and I have created links to other views using `presentViewController` but I can't figure out how to pass variables. How do I pass variables to the new view?

```
@IBAction func WorkoutPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let workoutView = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("workoutView") as WorkoutViewController
    self.presentViewController(workoutView, animated: false, completion: nil)
    //self.navigationController?.pushViewController(workoutView, animated: true)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `workoutView.someVariable = "yes, it's that easy"`

Comment: So, before self.presentViewController, I have a line that can add parameters? Where do I set which variables are the parameters?

Comment: Why are you calling them parameters? They are variables, even if you set them from outside of the object. If your viewController has a variable you can set it. Or did you set the variables of WorkoutViewController private? --- I would recommend that you edit your question to show an example of a variable that you can't set. There are a couple of possibilities that stop you from setting the variable from the outside. So maybe you encountered one of these. But you have to show some real code or we can't help.

Comment: You are correct. I should have said variable instead of parameter. I figured out how to do it with you tip. I built a variable in the new view and then set it's value in the previous view.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is easier than you think: you don't need to pass parameters because you can access class variables of the next view controller directly.

That is, you can do something like this:

```
workoutView.myVar = myVal
```

And, when that view loads, `myVar` will have the value `myVal`. (Don't forget to declare it in `WorkoutViewController`, though).